# Allowing a flex container with fixed position to shrink along with the viewport

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a way to make a flex container start with a certain width and then shrink with the viewport? Something like `flex-basis` but for the container.

I would like to know if there's a way to do it with "regular" CSS styles, without using queries and JavaScript.

For example `flex: 0 1 40rem;` would do exactly what I want but for the children of a flex container (even though they would shrink along with the parent width, not the viewport). Is it possible to do the same for the container?

Here is the CSS for the container I am trying to style. `max-width` won't work.

```css
.flex_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: lightGrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  max-width: 40rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <p>I am</p>
  <p>a flex container</p>
<div>
```

Comment: max-width:40rem is all what you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif But `max-width` defines only the upper limit and not both the initial width and the upper limit.

Comment: a block element is by default full width so by setting max-width you define this as its width and it will shrink with the viewport. You need to consider the result and not the meaning of the properties

Comment: @TemaniAfif max-width doesn't work. I edited the question with the styles I am trying to use

Comment: you have position:fixed that change everything .. you need to give more precise detail

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't know it was relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `max-width` you will need `right:0` (for this particular case of course)

```css
.flex_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 10%;
  right:0;
  background-color: lightGrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  max-width: 40rem;
  border:1px solid red ;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <p>I am</p>
  <p>a flex container</p>
<div>
```

Comment: So I can set the initial width with `right`, that's nice! Thank you, I will edit the question to point out the `position: fixed`

Comment: @SheikYerbouti it's not really right, it's max-width like explained in my comment. right will simply give back the full width behavior you lost by adding position:fixed (without it you don't need right)